# does not find directory or file in azure in python

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-active-directory

I made a script in python, locally executed successfully but in azure does not find the way, I did a test with pyspark just to see if it found the way and found but I don't know pyspark to turn this code into pyspark, how do I access a directory in azure ?

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime


origem  ='/mnt/caminho/teste.txt'
destino = "/mnt/caminho/teste.csv"

print(origem)
print(destino)

try:
    with open(origem, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as ler, open(destino, mode='w', encoding='UTF-8') as gravar:
        next(ler)
        next(ler)
        gravar.writelines(['data_puxada;','centro;','atribuicao;','ped_pca;','transporte;','fornecimento;','codigo_material;','descr_produto;','descr_status_pedido;','quantidade;','hora_puxada;','cliente;','cliente_sap;','numero_nota_fiscal;','data_inicio_carregamento;','hora_inicio_carregamento;','dt_termino_carregamento;','hora_termino_carregamento;','numeroov_pedtransf;','can_distrib;','tipo_operacao;','tipo_operacao;'])
        gravar.write('\n')
        next(ler)
        next(ler)


        for linha in ler:
            if  len(linha.strip()) > 0 and len(linha.strip("਍ഀ").strip()) > 0:
                linha = linha.rstrip()
                gravar.writelines(linha.replace('\t',';').strip()[:-2].rstrip()[1:].replace(".",'/',2).replace(".","",10))
                gravar.write('\n')
               #print(linha)



except AttributeError:
    print("Erro")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you excute the script locally you are using local disks.

When you run it in Azure, unless you run it in a VM, you do not have local disks.

You need to set up an Azure File Share and then configure your program to use it. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access, added **/dbfs/**, so it looks like this **/dbfs/mnt/caminho/teste.txt**